Trying to change value of table data via buttons inside table
I'm supposed to have two buttons in each row of a table that either lowers or raises the amount of votes by one and I'm having trouble figuring out how to proceed.
I've tried to use onclick and addEventListener but everything I try doesn't change the element at all.screenshot of code

Welcome to SO. Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please include all relevant code, including html, as text, preferably a Stack Snippet, in your question. What steps have you taken to debug this? Are there any errors in your dev console?
